# DOS Script to remove all .picasaoriginals folders

Tags: picasa

The issue is this. Using Plex to serve photos to a TV downstairs I have noticed many duplicated photos - this is caused by Google Picasa saving backups, and there appears to be no way to prevent this, even though we don't need them.

I need a DOS script that will search All folders and sub folders within \users\user\pictures\ and remove the .picasaoriginals folders (even if they contain .jpg pictures or not).

An example path might be:

users\user1\Pictures\HolidaySnaps.picasaoriginals

where holidaysnaps varies depending on album name...

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) to list all such folders, then:

1. select them all.
2. delete them with one click.